# How to use Sum in cakephp 3.8 querybuilder?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, sql-function

I have this simple code and I want to know how to use the cakephp 3.8 querybuilder to make a query and then how to fetch it..

```sql
SELECT sum(quantity) as quant from carts WHERE user_id = 7;
```

I am using this query:

```php
$quantity = $this->Carts
    ->find()
    ->select([
        'quant' => $quantity->func()->sum('quantity')
    ])
    ->where([
        'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    ])
    ->toArray();
```

Is this right?

I am getting this Error-
Call to a member function func() on null

Comment: Did you read [the manual section about this](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)?

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments, instead add it to your question, and describe the problem that you're having with it - thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit @ndm can you please give me solution to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$quantity` variable doesn't exist until after the query builder returns from the `toArray()` call, so you can't use it earlier in the `select()` call, and even afterwards the return value isn't a query builder instance anymore, but an array of results, as that is what `toArray()` will return.

Either store a reference to the query builder before invoking `select()`, like:

```
$quantityQuery = $this->Carts->find();
$quantity = $quantityQuery 
    ->select([
        'quant' => $quantityQuery->func()->sum('quantity')
    ])
    //...
```

or pass a callable to `select()`, it will retrieve the query instance as an argument:

```php
$quantity = $this->Carts
    ->find()
    ->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return [
            'quant' => $query->func()->sum('quantity')
        ];
    })
    //...
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**

Comment: how can I fetch the desired results from the query to set to the .ctp files

Comment: @Vishaal You probably want to read up on **https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-the-first-result** and **https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#accessing-entity-data**.